# How to combine on this logic of my date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I have a bad time thinking... IDK what to do it's almost a day still can't figure it out... this is my display and I want to be like this...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2E36.jpg

My Implementation

```
<?php
        $userId = (int) (!isset($_GET['id'])) ? 1 : $_GET['id'];
        $imagesResult = $db->getWhere("SELECT * FROM photo WHERE userID = {$userId} ORDER BY `when` DESC");
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($imagesResult);
        echo '</pre>';
        foreach ($imagesResult as $key => $value) {

            if(strtotime(date('j M Y', $value['when'])) == strtotime(date('j M Y'))) {
                echo "<div class='item'><h3>Today</h3></div>";

            } else {
                echo "<div class='item'><h3>".date('j M Y', $value['when'])."</h3></div>";
            }
            echo "
                <div class='item'>
                    <a href='photo.php?photoid={$value['id']}'><img src='img/picture/{$value['userId']}/{$value['imageLocation']}' height='180' /></a>
                </div>";
        }
    ?>
```

i don't know where to begin... that will return like that... it is hard to do when the date is outside the loop. i don't know where to put... please help me with this... just give me some little hints to do this...

**Sample Return of `$imageResult`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 35
            [userId] => 1
            [albumId] => 
            [imageLocation] => Background.png
            [description] => some description
            [tags] => 
            [when] => 1394965560
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 36
            [userId] => 1
            [albumId] => 
            [imageLocation] => Background1.png
            [description] => some description
            [tags] => 
            [when] => 1394965560
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I suggest instead of echoing results directly, you should build a final array GROUPED BY dates (including today).

Like this:

```
     $actualImageResults = array();
     foreach ($imagesResult as $Image) {
         $subarr = (date('j M Y', $Image['when']) == date('d M Y')) ? "today" : date("j-m-Y");
         if(!is_array($actualImageResults[$subarr])) $actualImageResults[$subarr] = array();
         array_push($actualImageResults[$subarr], $Image);
    }
```

And then `var_dump($actualImageResults)` to see if data is properly grouped...

After this you can go ahead an echo results:

```
foreach($actualImageResults as $stamp => $images) {
    echo "<strong>{$stamp}</strong>";
    foreach($images as $image) {
       echo $image["imageLocation"];
       /.../

    }
}
```

this is just a rough idea, you will need to make necessary adjustments according to your needs... but this is what I understand from your question and image link you posted. Its something like this -> making a final array from echoing having dates as its keys and all images grouped among them.

---

Issues:

I guess you are working in an environment with full error_reporting / debugging / etc... Turn off notices in error reporting on start of file. Something like:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
/.../
```

Comment: got this error `Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\InstaPUNX\profile.php on line 70` and change `$value['when']` to `$Image['when']`

Comment: Thank you for correction. Try now. Or if you are on PHP 5.4+ you could simply try:
$actualImageResults[$subarr][] = $image; instead of array_push.

Comment: I got this error `Undefined index: today`, `Undefined index: 16-03-2014` and many more... on your line `4`

Comment: Put this on top of your file... 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

Comment: apart from the notices, I believe array is working as expected?

Comment: answer updated... something like that you need... I am a little conjusted so couldnt go deeper

Answer (score 1):

Try using a flag variable:

```
    $userId = (int) (!isset($_GET['id'])) ? 1 : $_GET['id'];
    $imagesResult = $db->getWhere("SELECT * FROM photo WHERE userID = {$userId} ORDER BY `when` DESC");
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($imagesResult);
    echo '</pre>';
    $lastPrintedDateFlag = ""; // Flag variable
    foreach ($imagesResult as $key => $value) {
        if ($lastPrintedDateFlag != $value['when']) {
            $lastPrintedDateFlag = $value['when'];
            if(strtotime(date('j M Y', $value['when'])) == strtotime(date('j M Y'))) {
                echo "<div class='item'><h3>Today</h3></div>";

            } else {
                echo "<div class='item'><h3>".date('j M Y', $value['when'])."</h3></div>";
            }
        }
        echo "
            <div class='item'>
                <a href='photo.php?photoid={$value['id']}'><img src='img/picture/{$value['userId']}/{$value['imageLocation']}' height='180' /></a>
            </div>";
    }
```

---

But this is just a tricky way to archive what you want. I recommend to prepare a 2 dimensions array with images grouped by date, then you will print the result more clearly:

Example of the array:

```
Array
(
    [16-03-14] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                  (
                   [id] => 35
                   [userId] => 1
                   [albumId] => 
                   [imageLocation] => Background.png
                   [description] => some description
                   [tags] => 
                   [when] => 1394965560
               ),
            [2] => Array
                  (
                   [id] => 35
                   [userId] => 1
                   [albumId] => 
                   [imageLocation] => Background.png
                   [description] => some description
                   [tags] => 
                   [when] => 1394965560
               )
        )
    [17-03-14] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                  (
                   [id] => 35
                   [userId] => 1
                   [albumId] => 
                   [imageLocation] => Background.png
                   [description] => fuck this Shit
                   [tags] => 
                   [when] => 1394965560
               )
        )
)
```